# Apple ID review information

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, apple-id

I tried downloading apps with my new Apple ID and it asked me to review it. After filling in the information it shows an error and asks me to insert a billing address with atmost 70 letters or numbers. My address that I mentioned is correct. How do I get past this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried logging on to the iTunes store on your computer rather than an iOS device?

That will usually allow the account to settle and allow you to start purchasing apps.

Answer (score 0):

I would enter the first 60 letters of the address field in question to get the computer to accept things.

Then you could use your postal website (or local postmaster) to determine if your address has a suitable official abbreviation to make it both correct and amenable to the field limits Apple has.

You can also always contact Apple Support to get assistance in correcting your Apple ID and store account information.

- http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/